# Number of equilateral triangles in triangular grid

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, triangles

[image: triangle image]

How can we find the number $f(x, y)$ of equilateral triangles that can be made by connecting three points within boundaries $x$ and $y$? (Suppose that $x\le y$)

[image: f(1, 4)]

For example, $f(1, 4) = 15$ because there are $9$ smallest triangles, $3$ triangles that are twice as large, $1$ triangles that are 3 times as large, and $2$ triangle that is turned ($90$ degrees or $270$ degrees each).

[image: f(3, 6)]

example $2$ : $f(3, 6) = 21 + 7 + 3 + 5 + 5 + 3 + 1 + 1 = 46$

- I am aware that the difficulty level of this problem is difficult. (I've been thinking about solving this for more than two days.) If it is impossible to find $f(x, y)$ in one formula, I would appreciate it if you could tell me the generalized calculation method. Thank you!

Comment: On which ground this question should be closed ?

Comment: What do $x,y$ count? And in the picture you posted what are $x$ and $y$? Can you please better explain what $f$ is?

Comment: @JeanMarie
1. It is correct to count the number incorrectly.
2. Lack of expression. (I can't speak English, so I'm using a translator.)
I will revise the contents. I'm sorry.

Comment: @lcv Sorry. I have attached additional pictures.

Comment: Have you noticed that for $x=1$, the number of small triangles is 1, then 1+3=4, then 1+3+5=9, then 1+3+5+7=16, etc. all of them squares. This is a classical result : the sum of the first n **odd** numbers is $n^2$. Therefore the general formula for the number of small triangles should be $y^2-x^2+1$.

Comment: Interesting question (+1). I think you could still make it clearer but I get what you mean. Side question: how did this problem arise?

Comment: A cousin question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/195486/305862

Comment: @JeanMarie I think what makes this question difficult and interesting (even for $x=1$) is the relaxed assumption that does not require the sides of the triangle to be on the grid lines - see the last two examples in each group.